# Getting warning when trying to use router.history.goBack with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I getting this warning:

*Warning: BackButton: type specification of context `router` is invalid; the type checker function must return `null` or an `Error` but returned a boolean. You may have forgotten to pass an argument to the type checker creator (arrayOf, instanceOf, objectOf, oneOf, oneOfType, and shape all require an argument).*

Here is my code (its a BackButton component I want to reuse)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from 'antd';

class BackButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: () => true,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}>
        Back
      </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default BackButton;
```

**I would preferable use PropTypes instead if possible, but I do not know how...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example with propTypes:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // You need to add this dependency

class BackButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}>
        Back
      </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default BackButton;
```

You can read more about propTypes here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html.

Answer (score 1):

The `contextTypes` for router need to be defined like `PropTypes.object.isRequired`, install `prop-type`s from npm first using

```
npm install -S prop-types
```

and import it like

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

and define context as

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

so you code will look like

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
class BackButton extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}>
        Back
      </Button>
    )
  }
}
```